# Electron CustomScheme - What do the various privileges mean?

Tags: node.js, electron, protocols

Referring to these docs: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/structures/custom-scheme

What do these privileges actually do? Especially uncertain about `standard`, `secure,` and `stream`:

- `privileges` Object (optional)

  - `standard` boolean (optional) - Default false.
  - `secure` boolean (optional) - Default false.
  - `bypassCSP` boolean (optional) - Default false.
  - `allowServiceWorkers` boolean (optional) - Default false.
  - `supportFetchAPI` boolean (optional) - Default false.
  - `corsEnabled` boolean (optional) - Default false.
  - `stream` boolean (optional) - Default false.

Answer (score 2):

Options `standard`, `secure`, `bypassCSP` and `corsEnabled` are corresponding to chromium methods described in [this file](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/url/url_util.h#80).

Therefore, the `secure` option means that this scheme will not trigger mixed content warnings.

Options `allowServiceWorkers` and `supportFetchAPI` are used to register this scheme in the chromium engine as supporting service workers and the fetch API, respectively.

The option `stream` specify this scheme will be used for audio or video streaming.